# React good practice - how to structure Parent and Child components including forms and where to keep state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about reacts good practices when it comes to forms as to where to keep state (only parent etc). 2 approaches below:

1. Child (the form and input fields) has own onChange event and has state, only passes onsubmit the values back to parent and parent only passes down function to pass back those values
2. this approach Ive seen more. Child has no state (seems better as then the child is really just a presentational component and parent stores all the data and has state). However, then child passes 'back' the values on each onChange event (with each letter typed), ONLY to receive BACK the value it 'gave' to parent (since inputs need value most cases), which seems like back and forth data passing =waste?

I created 2 small versions to demonstrate. I would really appreciate opinions as to what way is better, since Im always wondering.
Thank you!!

```
 class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: "",
        country: "",
        result: ""
    }

    onChange = (key, val) => {
        this.setState({
            [key]: val
        })
    }
    onSubmit = () => {
        this.state({
            result: this.state.name + " is from " + this.state.country
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child onChange={this.onChange} name={this.state.name} country={this.state.country}/>
                <h1>{this.state.result}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Child = ({onChange, onSubmit, name, country}) => {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input name="name" placeholder="name" value={name}
                   onChange={({target: {name, value}}) => onChange(name, value)}/>
            <input name="country" placeholder="country" value={country}
                   onChange={({target: {name, value}}) => onChange(name, value)}/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    )
};
```

2nd version, where I keep state inside the child

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        result: ""
    };
    onSubmit = (event, name, country) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            result: name + " is from " + country
        })
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>
                <h1>{this.state.result}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    state = {};
    onChange = ({target: {name, value}}) => {
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={() => this.props.onSubmit(event, this.state.name, this.state.country)}>
                <input name="name" placeholder="name" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.name}/>
                <input name="country" placeholder="country" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.country}/>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```